# Ansible: loop on files to do POST requests

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to invoke some REST API and do some POST requests to the service with Ansible. Since the body (JSON) changes, I'm trying to do a loop on some files. Here is the playbook:

---

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  any_errors_fatal: true

  tasks:
    - name: do post requests                                            
      uri:
        url: "https://XXXX.com"
        method: POST
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
        body: "{{ lookup('file', "{{ item }}" ) }}"
        with_file:
          - server1.json
          - server2.json
          - proxy.json
```

But when I run the playbook, I get this error:

> the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'item' is undefined

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `with_` directive should belong to a task dictionary (one indentation level up).

The second problem is that you should use either `with_items` with file lookup, or simply `"{{ item }}"` with `with_files`:

```
- name: do post requests                                            
  uri:
    url: "https://XXXX.com"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
    body: "{{ item }}"
  with_files:
    - server1.json
    - server2.json
    - proxy.json
```

or

```
- name: do post requests                                            
  uri:
    url: "https://XXXX.com"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      X-Auth-Token: "XXXXXX"
    body: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
  with_items:
    - server1.json
    - server2.json
    - proxy.json
```

---

Besides, `{{ ... }}` construct is not a required way to refer to each and every variable -- it is a construct opening a Jinja2 expressions inside which you use variables. For a single variable it indeed becomes: `{{ variable }}`, but once you open it, you don't need to do it again, so it's perfectly fine to write:

```
body: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
```

Comment: Another question. The solution you have provided works fine, but now i get this error: Unable to find (...content of server1.json...) in expected paths. The json files are in the same directory of the playbook, what would be the problem here?